# How to apply local styles to imported React components

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, css-loader

I am trying to figure out how I get CSS to be successfully applied to components that I import from an npm library.

The core of my issue seems to be that I'm using css-loader as part of the react starter kit (https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) and don't fully understand how it works.

I have looked at a couple of datepicker libraries - for example https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime and https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment.

In each case, the source code is applying local class names to the HTML.  The formats that are embedded in the libraries aren't automatically applied.  I've tried importing them manually from /node_modules in the component that uses the library component.  I've also tried copying the relevant styles to a local css file and importing that.

The issue appears to be that css-loader is converting any imported styles class names to be module-specific class names which then don't match the actual class names in the resulting HTML.

Am I approaching this wrong?  What's the preferred way to import components and apply custom styling to them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears all I needed to do was add :global() around the classnames in the css file.  For example:

```css
:global(.myclass) {
   color:red;
  }
```

That preserves the classnames without transformation and so they hit the HTML.  Not sure if this is best practice or not, but it worked.